# Routers backbones.js, problema con rutas

Tags: jquery, backbone

Estoy usando el framework Backbone.js y estoy utilizando los routers para crear urls en mi página.

Resulta que creo que ya lo tengo, pero cuando abro la consola del Chrome me dice lo siguiente:

`backbone.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Es raro porque utilizo los mismos patrones que en los ejemplos que he encontrado.

Os dejo el código:

```
 (function(){
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {

            "boton1/:id" : "vistauno"
            "boton2/:id" : "vistados"
            "boton3/:id" : "vistatres"
    },

      vistauno: function (boton1) {
          console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton1);
    },
      vistados: function (boton2) {
          console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton2);
    },
      vistatres: function (boton3) {
          console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton3);
    }

  });
      var Router = new Router();
      Backbone.history.start();
  })();
```

El error parece estar en la linea 7, en `"boton2/:id" : "vistados"`, pero me resulta raro por que todos los ejemplos que he mirado lo hacen igual..

Comment: Prueba de poner comas `,` entre la 1a y segunda línea y la 2a y la 3a línea de las rutas: `"boton1/:id" : "vistauno",
            "boton2/:id" : "vistados",
            "boton3/:id" : "vistatres"`

Comment: pufff! Vale eso era, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo te he comentado en los comentarios el problema era un simple `typo`. En la definición de `routes` es necesario separar cada elemento con una `,` siendo este el resultado:

```
(function(){
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {

        "boton1/:id" : "vistauno", //<-- Necesario
        "boton2/:id" : "vistados", //<-- Necesario
        "boton3/:id" : "vistatres"
},

  vistauno: function (boton1) {
      console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton1);
},
  vistados: function (boton2) {
      console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton2);
},
  vistatres: function (boton3) {
      console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton3);
}
});
   var Router = new Router();
   Backbone.history.start();
})();
```